# How to associate submit button with only one value

Tags: php, html, sql

I have multiple submit buttons with the same name in my ongoing table, i want to have each submit button contains only one link. So whenever i click on a button, it generates a link that the submit is associated with. How to do it?

```
<input type="submit" value="<? $row['bclink'] ?>" name="re_b" id="re_b">
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['re_b'])){

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($re_b);

}
```

this is what i have, but it's giving me an error that "simplexml_load_file() failed to load external entity "" in .... on line 70"

my question is how to call the value of the button when is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

What error? If you have a problem, then give some details, don't just say you have a problem and expect us to be able to read it from your thoughts. No one here has taken Telepathy 101.

Do you mean you want something like this?

```
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Something" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Else" />


   if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Something') {
      ... 
   } else if ($_POST'submit'] = 'Else') {
      ...
   }
```

Comment: thank you. as i mentioned in the original post. it's a ongoing table, all the submit buttons have the same name with different value. is it possible?

Comment: Sure. As long as the value is different for each one, the `if()` I put above is how you'd check for those different values. If all the submit buttons have the same name and values, then you have no way of differentiating them. A submit button's name/value shows up no differently on th eserver than a text field or a checkbox. it'll just a simple `name=value` pair.

Comment: i wasn't able to submit this: instead of having value ="link", it is actually value = "<? $row['link'] ?>"
so everything is retrieved from the database, i don't have the values assigned

Comment: Then what's wrong with your original code? It'd do a fetch on whatever url is in the submit button's value field.

Comment: correct, thats what it should do.. sorry for making it unclear at first.
it gave me a warning "simplexml_load_file() failed to load external entity "" in .... on line 70. 

this is actually what i have: <input type="submit" value="<? $row['bclink'] ?>" name="re_b" id="re_b">

Comment: Ah. that's not an HTML/php problem, it's the fact that the external document you're loading (presumably HTML) contains a character entity which is NOT recognized by XML. XML only recognizes 5 entities, while HTML has literally hundreds.

Comment: i just want to make sure that i have the right idea right? because i've been working on this for quite a long time, still haven't found a way to solve it. btw i've made some edition to the original post. what i am trying to do is to load the value inside the submit button

Comment: Looks ok, but again... the error is due to bad XML... the problem isn't with anything you've coded in PHP. The problem lies in that file you're trying to load into simplexml.